# Does sotapanna still experience afflictive thoughts?

Tags: unwholesome

Does a sotapanna still experience afflictive thoughts and or engage in unwholesome activities etc or have they transcended such things?

Answer (score 1):

For the most part, sotapanna do not engage in unwholesome activities or have afflictive thoughts because they have no doubt about the Path due to directly experiencing the peacefulness of abandoning self-identity view & associated unwholesome mental states. However, a sotapanna can have a lapse of mindfulness & insufficient wisdom, causing some minor affliction & minor unwholesome activity.

Some quotes from  the Pali Suttas about sotapanna are:

> There is the case where a monk is wholly accomplished in virtue, moderately accomplished in concentration and moderately accomplished in discernment. With reference to the lesser and minor training rules, he falls into offenses and rehabilitates himself. Why is that? Because I have not declared that to be a disqualification in these circumstances. But as for the training rules that are basic to the holy life and proper to the holy life, he is one of permanent virtue, one of steadfast virtue. Having undertaken them, he trains in reference to the training rules. With the wasting away of [the first] three fetters, he is a stream-winner, never again destined for states of woe, certain, headed for self-awakening.
>
> [AN 3.86](https://suttacentral.net/an3.86/en/thanissaro?lang=en&reference=none&highlight=false)

> The noble listener
> succeeding in view,
> a person who has overcome,
> has thoroughly burnt off,
> thoroughly given up that which is the greater pain,
> of small measure is that which remains
> not even a hundredth part does it come to,
> not a thousandth part,
> not a hundred-thousandth part
> does it come to;
> being here seven more times tops,
> is of small measure compared to
> that former pile of dukkha (suffering; affliction) of his
> which has been thoroughly burnt off,
> thoroughly given up.
>
> [SN 13.1](https://obo.genaud.net/dhamma-vinaya/bd/sn/02_nv/sn02.13.001.olds.bd.htm)

> Now, a trifling evil deed done by what sort of individual is experienced in the here & now, and for the most part barely appears for a moment? There is the case where a certain individual is developed in [contemplating] the body, developed in virtue, developed in mind, developed in discernment: unrestricted, large-hearted, dwelling with the immeasurable. A trifling evil deed done by this sort of individual is experienced in the here & now, and for the most part barely appears for a moment.
>
> [AN 3.99](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/an/an03/an03.099.than.html)

Answer (score 1):

Yes a sotapanna may not be immune to conceit for example:

- [How are 'conceit' and 'identity-view' not the same?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/9415/254)

Note that conceit is canonically a source or perhaps *the* source of conflict (such as arguing about points of Dhamma) -- assuming you even consider that "unwholesome activity" and "afflictive":

- [Wikipedia: Māna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C4%81na)

And a sottapana may not have (yet) uprooted other afflictions or fetters, including sensual desire, ill-will, etc.

- [Wikipedia: Lists of fetters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fetter_(Buddhism)#Lists_of_fetters)